# Android projects not running in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

I am facing a so weird issue with my eclipse. Android projects are not running in my eclipse 
I'm using 
**Eclipse version 4.4 Luna** , 
**android SDK latest API level 23** 
(even earlier versions is not working ).It was running well till some days ago , and all other java projects running fine like web and desktop etc.. 
Whenever I am running the android project it shows the error dialog box, though no errors are there in the project(for a new project also), I have tried clean build, cleared cache, updated eclipse adt , and is there anything left I need to try other than formatting PC?

Comment: use Android studio its better

Comment: Well , that I know , but what should I do here? It is happening only in my PC , May I get a solution rather than formatting?

Comment: `it shows the error dialog box` Which one? What does your logcat say? Did you make some upgrades? Be aware that Google is sabotating Eclipse. So, upgrades may not be safe.

Comment: For better approach,switch to Android studio

Comment: It shows error message like usual error for project. nothing in my logcat .. I have upgraded eclipse but it was not working before upgrade also...if Google is sabotating eclipse then it should happen in other PCs too right? but problem is with my pc :(

Comment: Can you post the errormessage you see?

Comment: As @Amit said , try using Android Studio as it will do most of the corrections like the but the start-up problems and cache recovery by itself.

Comment: @gletherin : It is the normal error message box we see when the project contains error ..should I post a screen shot ?

Comment: `but problem is with my pc` because, possibly, you made an update on that PC.

Comment: I have updated only eclipse and sdk ,but only after when things stopped working ... I thought it was the problem with the old version !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ,after some struggle I have found out what is the actual problem. It was my debug.keystore file.

I have got an error in my console saying **Debug certificate expired**

Well I have found my debug.keysotre file in here **%USERPROFILE%/.android** and deleted it. Eclipse itself will generate a new one when compiling a new project. You may need to clean and then build to generate the certificate.

Thanks everyone for your support.

Problem solved !!! :)